# lightweight cross-platform message queue for IPC

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

I am looking for a lightweight message queue (IPC), that is cross-platform (linux, windows).

I have used msgget, msgsnd, and msgrcv. But this is not cross-platform so wouldn't work on windows.

I don't need any socket layer (tcp, udp). As all the messaging will be on the same server.

Basically, I have an event loop and I will block (separate thread) until I get a message from the message queue (msgrcv). Then process that event. The messages will come from another shared library that I have created that I will monitor events from in my event loop.

I just want to be able to send message to the message queue (msgsnd) and then receive them (msgrcv) in my event loop.

Comment: Will messages come from different _processes_ or different _threads_ from the same _process_?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there're two such things: [ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) and [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

ØMQ is the socket library that acts as a concurrency framework, suitable for asynch I/O for scalable multicore message-passing apps. It supports most OSes including Linux, Windows, OS X.

Gearman allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages. In other words, it is the nervous system for how distributed processing communicates.

Comment: Note that zmq both have inprocess and IPC transports, it's not only using TCP/IP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can check our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) (free licenses are available). MsgConnect is a cross-platform (including Linux and Windows) message-oriented middleware framework, designed for easy sending of messages on the same computer or across network.

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure, you should probably mention that you work for the company that makes MsgConnect.

Comment: @EvanHaas is the word "our" obfuscated so much?

Comment: Ah, my mistake (I read "check out" instead of "check our").  IMHO, you should still make the disclaimer more prominent...